# Certbot can't install certificate on nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, certbot

I have a mysterious error when I try to install a certificate on nginx with certbot. I get the following output when I run `certbot --authenticator webroot --installer nginx`:

`nginx: [emerg] a duplicate listen 0.0.0.0:443 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/00-default-ssl.conf:8`

The mysterious part is I do not have a duplicate listen in any conf file imported by nginx :

```
root@mail:/etc/nginx# grep -R listen /etc/nginx
/etc/nginx/sites-conf.d/default/0-listen.conf:listen 80;
/etc/nginx/sites-conf.d/default/0-listen.conf:
# Note: this setting listens on both ipv4 and ipv6 with Nginx release
/etc/nginx/sites-conf.d/default/0-listen.conf:#listen [::]:80;
/etc/nginx/sites-conf.d/default-ssl/0-listen.conf:listen 443;
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.2018.03.04.14.54.26:#  listen localhost:110;
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.2018.03.04.14.54.26:#  listen localhost:143;
```

Does anybody know where the duplicate might be ?
Thanks

Comment: Then what do you have on line 8 of /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/00-default-ssl.conf ?

Comment: Is the file being included twice? You could try `nginx -T` to see the entire configuration as `nginx` sees it.

Comment: This is /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/00-default-ssl.conf:
`#
# Note: This file must be loaded before other virtual host config files,
#
# HTTPS
server {
    include /etc/nginx/sites-conf.d/default-ssl/*.conf;
}`

I can't see where a second inclusion of the listen command might be when I `nginx -T` either.
I tried to remove some included files which seemed to be included twice but it didn't work...

Comment: Hey, did you end up solving this? If so what was the solution?